# How to filter rows and words in lower case in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I would like to know how to select rows which contains lower cases in the following dataframe:

```
ID     Name   Note
1      Fin    there IS A dog outside
2      Mik    NOTHING TO DECLARE
3      Lau    no house
```

What I would like to do is to filter rows where Note column contains at least one word in lower case:

```
ID     Name   Note
1      Fin    there IS A dog outside
3      Lau    no house
```

and collect in a list all the words in lower case: `my_list=['there','dog','outside','no','house']`

I have tried to filter rows is :

```
df1=df['Note'].str.lower()
```

For appending words in the list, I think I should first tokenise the string, then select all the terms in lower case. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for filter at least one lowercase character in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['Note'].str.contains(r'[a-z]')]
print (df1)
   ID Name                    Note
0   1  Fin  there IS A dog outside
2   3  Lau                no house
```

And then [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for extract lowercase words:

```
my_list = df1['Note'].str.extractall(r'(\b[a-z]+\b)')[0].tolist()
print (my_list)
['there', 'dog', 'outside', 'no', 'house']
```

Or use list comprehension with split sentences and filter by `islower`:

```
my_list = [y for x in df1['Note'] for y in x.split() if y.islower()]
print (my_list)
['there', 'dog', 'outside', 'no', 'house']
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jezrael. May I ask you why I cannot use str.lower but it is preferable to use str.contains?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro - Because `str.lower()` only convert all values to lowercase, here you want filter by lowercase.

Comment: Last question: why do you add [0] before tolist()?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro - `extractall` return one column DataFrame with `0` column, for select column is used `[0]`. If omit it get different output, because not Series